# SQL - Bring back sales transactions with 2 specific items in it AND/OR

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a piece of SQL code that will bring back all sales transaction numbers with 2 specific items in it which I input. I just can't get the items part correct.

```
SELECT *
FROM [mastertable] TSE
WHERE TSE.Date BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160501'
AND TSE.[Store No_] = '####'
AND TSE.[Item No_] = '133033'
AND TSE.[Item No_] = '144086`
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Give this a go;

```
SELECT *
FROM [mastertable] TSE
WHERE TSE.Date BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160501'
AND TSE.[Store No_] = '####'
AND (TSE.[Item No_] = '133033'
OR TSE.[Item No_] = '144086`)
```

The reason your code wasn't working is that the item no needed to be both 113033 and 144086, you want it to be either of these. You could also update this to something like below;

```
AND TSE.[Item No_] IN ('133033','144086')
```

Although this will be optimised the same way.

Reading your responses that mention your item number should contain either of these numbers, is this what you're after?

```
SELECT *
FROM [mastertable] TSE
WHERE TSE.Date BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160501'
AND TSE.[Store No_] = '####'
AND TSE.[Item No_] LIKE '%133033%'
and TSE.[Item No_] LIKE '%144086%')
```

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for the response. However, this is still not giving me the desired results. I would like the query to only bring back any sales transactions numbers (receipt numbers) that have both these items in the sale. Does this make sense?

Comment: If you update your original query with the schema of [mastertable] and an example of the data i can take a look. I'm flying blind without this i'm afraid.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. It will work perfectly.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    [mastertable] TSE
WHERE 
    TSE.Date BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20160501'
    AND TSE.[Store No_] = '####'
    AND TSE.[Item No_] IN ('133033','144086')
```

Comment: Hi Praveen, Thanks for the reply. This doesn't answer my query as some transaction numbers are the same for different stores. Eg. there could be transaction number 63 for 3 stores. I would like if I could just get any transaction number with both these items in it. as the code you provided above brings back transaction numbers with either of these items.

Comment: I am not getting a clear picture of what you exactly mean.